# Ошибка php Parse error

Tags: php, sql

```
$login = $_GET['login'];
$password = $_GET['password'];


if ($count = mysqli_query($conection, 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password'')) {
if (mysqli_num_rows ($count) == 0 )
{
    echo 'Вы не зарегестрированы';
} else {
    echo 'Привет'.$login;
}
```

}

При выполнении этого кода выдает ошибку :
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$login' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'**
Помогите пожалуйста найти проблему

Comment: Пароль в открытом виде - хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел ошибку

```
if ($count = mysqli_query($conection, 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password''))
```

в этой строке нужно было изменить кавычки, перед кодом SQL

```
if ($count = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password'")) {
```